# Links not working in Linkedin Company Insider Plugin

Tags: linkedin-api

I am working with the Company Insider Plugin and have noticed what I believe is a bug.

Here is the code for the embedded plugin:

And here is a screenshot of it embedded on the page:

[Company Insider Plugin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xytnf.png)

The top link that purports to show the company's connections in your network leads to an error page.

Comment: there is no code for the embedded plugin

Answer (score 0):

I believe you forgot the code for the embedded plugin

[here is what your post looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pBAav.png)